# angucomplete + django-rest-framework

Tags: django, angularjs

I want to use Django-REST-Framework as backend for angucomplete. The problem is that DRF returns a list of objects straight away without wrapping it in a dictionary (response is something like [item, item, item] instead of {results: [item, item, item]}) and I don't know how to teel angucomplete where to look for the list.

I know I can tinker with fields and serializers but I want to keep things as simple as it is possible, without any additional boilerplate.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

What calls are you making to DRF that returns that result object?

If you have paginated results (and you should) the result objects should be like the following:

`{
    "results": [
        ...
    ]
}`

You can read more about paginated results [in the DRF documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination).